# What is UEFI? How do I know if I have it?

Tags: bios, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if my BIOS supports UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/304004/how-to-know-if-my-bios-supports-uefi)

Just watched the [Win8 keynote thing](http://www.buildwindows.com/), and seemed like the fast boot times required something called UEFI(?). What is that? How do I know if I have it? And if I do have support for it, do I have to do something to enable it, or is it "already there" sort of?

Comment: If you do not have it there is no way to add it.

Answer (score 3):

[`Unified Extensible Firmware Interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), see specifically [Platforms using EFI/UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Platforms_using_EFI.2FUEFI).

Answer (score 3):

This is the successor of the good old BIOS.

Many modern servers already have UEFI, there mostly resulting in longer boot-times.
Mac-systems (with Intel-Processors) also rely on UEFI.