# Toshiba Qosmio and UEFI

Tags: toshiba-laptop, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if my BIOS supports UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/304004/how-to-know-if-my-bios-supports-uefi)

I have a Toshiba Qosmio X505-Q888 and I was wondering if there was a way to have UEFI installed on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what b01 says in that if the hardware doesn't support (U)EFI then you aren't going to find a "Real" EFI that you can make work with it, as the computer needs the hardware to be able to  support the EFI firmware (which are very different from a BIOS firmware), as well as any new thing(s) the EFI system does differently than a BIOS.

Depending on what you want to do though, you may be able to get away with a "fake" EFI implementation, and there's (at least) a couple out there due to people making x86 Hackintosh computers.

- netkas' [PC_EFI](http://netkas.org/?cat=5)
- [Chameleon](http://chameleon.osx86.hu/)

Answer (score 1):

No, UEFI is a replacement for BIOS, not something to be install like a video card. The board in that laptop has to already use UEFI in place of a BIOS chip.

[Read here to get an idea of what UEFI is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

One way to know is if you go into the motherboard settings, if you see more than 16/256 colors, then you can assume it has a UEFI firmware (just kidding). Even better, I think my board at work states UEFI when I go into the firmware settings.