# Do any laptops currently support UEFI Secure-Boot?

Tags: uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if my BIOS supports UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/304004/how-to-know-if-my-bios-supports-uefi)

Despite all of the bad press recently regarding UEFI secure-boot, I'm actually interested in getting a system which has this technology.

Since the x86/x64 laptop / desktop manufacturers are being required by the Windows Logo certification process to allow people to disable UEFI secure-boot, and my favorite Linux distros are working things out, it looks like I can only gain from the potential security advantages against root-kits, etc. (I know there are problems with ARM right now -- I'm not interested in buying an ARM-based laptop at the moment, so let's not get sidetracked).

I'm currently looking to purchase a new laptop (my 4 year old HP is going down fast) and was considering Lenovo's new T530. Lenovo says nothing regarding secure-boot on their website, but since this system was just released, I imagine they will be selling it in the Fall when Windows 8 arrives. Based on this, I imagine this machine probably has the secure-boot technology, or may be able to get it with a firmware upgrade.

Two questions:

1. If a machine has UEFI, does this automatically mean it has UEFI secure-boot? I can't find anything that says it does.
2. If the answer to #1 is no, have any manufacturers come out and said their current systems (specifically laptops) support UEFI secure-boot? Will this functionality perhaps be added as a firmware update to newer models released?

Comment: Looks like I can answer at least question 1 -- UEFI does not mean UEFI secure boot, as it must be at least version 2.3.1 of the UEFI firmware (http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Windows-8-to-include-secure-boot-using-UEFI-2-3-1-1335246.html)

Comment: @Diogo As I noted in my above, having UEFI != having UEFI secure boot.